# A family out of place?

Tags: riddle

On this neighbor hood, there lives five families.

Four of the families have three story houses.

One family, only has a 2 story house,

and it is built at the end of the neighborhood.

What is this neighborhood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The neighbourhood is:

> **A hand**. The 5 'families' are the 4 fingers and the thumb. Each of the fingers has 3 phalanx bones (3 'storeys') while the thumb ('at the end of the neighbourhood') has only 2 phalanx bones (2 'storeys').

Comment: I think there are typos...

Comment: @entioneveryone If you're referring to 'story' and 'storey' that's just a UK vs US English thing :) If it's something else, do say!